# Where to Put Random.Choice so That is it Rerun Each Time, But Accessible to All Code? (Kivy/Python)

Tags: python, kivy

So before people roast me or this gets removed, I know my question is unclear. I'm a python novice and StackOverflow is clearer to me than tutorials. Please have mercy?

I have a dictionary app. At start, you see a word and a text box inviting you to define said word. At the bottom is a "submit" button. Once pressed, a text appears saying "[same word] defined as: xyz", and a "restart" button appears.

Here's where my problems begin.

Pressing "restart" returns the same word to define, ie, it's picking the same string from my text file. This is because I have `word = random.choice(words)` as a global variable. If it's NOT  a global variable, then I have to put `random.choice(words)` in both the main code and the restart function. This causes the displayed word to define to be different from the "[word] defined as:" text which is displayed upon pressing submit. A picture is below for clarity.

[image]

**IN BRIEF - How can I make `random.choice(words)` return the same string for both the top label, and bottom text, while having this word CHANGE upon pressing restart?**

````
class Mygridlayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):


        super(Mygridlayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.Top_Grid = GridLayout()
        self.Top_Grid.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(self.Top_Grid)
        self.cols = 1
        self.Top_Grid.add_widget(Label(text=word))
        self.definition = TextInput(multiline='true')
        self.Top_Grid.add_widget(self.definition)
        self.submit = Button(text='submit')
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)


    def restart (self, instance):


        self.clear_widgets()
        self.Top_Grid = GridLayout()
        self.Top_Grid.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(self.Top_Grid)
        self.cols = 1
        self.Top_Grid.add_widget(Label(text=word))
        self.definition = TextInput(multiline='true')
        self.Top_Grid.add_widget(self.definition)
        self.submit = Button(text='submit')
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code for when the user presses "submit" so it will be difficult to answer the question precisely. If your `restart` code is used for both SUBMIT and RESTART actions, then that is part of the problem.

You *do* need to call `random.choice(words)` in both `__init__` and `restart`. No way around that, it's the only way to get a new word. The call in `restart` must take place after the user presses the RESTART button.

[The `word` variable can be global or inside the `Mygridlayout` class. Whichever, the assignment to `word` happens in init and restart, and submit uses the stored value.]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I have to call ```random.choice``` in both places, how can I assure that the given value is the same?

Comment: The point of calling random.choice is to get a _different_ word, not the same. You need to have different code for SUBMIT [where word should _not_ be changed] and RESTART [where word _should_ be changed].